# How to send API call when the payload contains lists and objects?

Tags: python, request, postman

I need to send a Post request via Python code, like using Postman.

When I look at the Payload tab under the Network in Google Chrome I see this data:

```
version: abcd
password: Somepassowrd
links[0].XYZ: DC-DC-02-01
links[0].Change: 4321
```

How to send links[0].xyz? Is is a dictionary or an object?

```
data = {'Token': settings.TOKEN,
                'links': [{'xyz': 'DC-DC-02-01',
                            'Change': 4321}],
                'version': abcd, 'password': 'SomePassword'}
```

Send Request with this data always give me code 500 and "Internal server error":

```
response = self.api.post(url=url, form=data,
                                     ignore_https_errors=True)
```

Comment: Are you able to see an actual error? Looks like it should be an object. Have you tried using Json to dump it?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the code you have posted it seems that in the "Change" property you have indeed capitalized the first "C". However, in xyz you have put it all in lowercase. Could this be the error?
Indeed, as you point out links is an array of objects with the properties: XYZ and Change

Answer (score 0):

Convert dict to string prior to sending request.

```
str()
```